# How to add shortcut key in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

With the reference video below. How can i add shortcut key to screen & multiply. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[Reference video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_91sWI5crU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Menu **Edit** → **Keyboard Shortcuts**.

With the **Tools** pop up menu selected, go down until the **Blend Modes** and set the shortcuts.

[image]